# angular "checked" radio on preset model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this bootstrap / angular template code, used to set the alignment of an image:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in attributes">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-white" ng-click="align(a, 0)">
            <input type="radio" name="{{a.id}}" ng-checked="{checked : (a.numericValue === 0)}">
            Left
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-white" ng-click="align(a, 1)">
            <input type="radio" name="{{a.id}}" ng-checked="{checked : (a.numericValue === 1)}">
            Center
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-white" ng-click="align(a, 2)">
            <input type="radio" name="{{a.id}}" ng-checked="{checked : (a.numericValue === 2)}">
            Right
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="clip text-{{align(a)}}">
        <img alt="#" ng-src="a.image">
    </div>
</div>
```

Clicking on the resulting button, is rightly updated the model, than the method returns the right css class.

When the buttons are rendered, the status is handled by bootstrap and everything is ok. What I cannot do is to set the initial checked status on the button.

I tried also using expressions, but does not work:

```
{{(a.numericValue == 0) && 'checked' || ''}}
```

or also:

```
checked="{{(a.numericValue == 0) && 'checked' || ''}}"
```

What can I do to set the initial value?

Thanks a lot, Davide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not using angularJS + radio correctly. look to [angularjs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)

your radio button should be like that

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="a.numericValue" value="0"> Left
....
<input type="radio" ng-model="a.numericValue" value="1"> Center
....
<input type="radio" ng-model="a.numericValue" value="2"> Right
```

So, to initialize the checked status, just set the a.numericValur to initial value desired in controller

```
a.numericValue = 0;
```

AngularJS check the a.numericValue with the value attribute of radio button.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! There are two problems about it: 1 value is a string instead a number and the match is done using the string representation of the number. I solved using mg-value in place of value.

Comment: The second one was that I missed the "active" class on label :D ops... Now it works and is much more simple :)